# AVE syntax with second-order lantent variable

Tags: r

Help on the AVE syntax with second-order latent variable.

Here is the background, I am working on the measurement model and below syntax is the final selection:

```
`model6 <- 'fluency =~ Fluen1+Fluen2+Fluen3+Fluen4 
       transportation=~ Trans3+Trans9+Trans11
      attention =~ Attn1+ Attn2+ Attn4
      affective=~ BrAtt2+BrAtt3+BrAtt4+BrAtt5
      cognitive=~ BrAtt6+BrAtt7+BrAtt8+BrAtt9
      conative=~ BrAtt10+BrAtt11
      brandattitude= ~BrAtt1+affective+cognitive+conative
    Luxury= ~Lux14+Lux18+Lux11+Lux12+Lux13
      transportability= ~STrans1+STrans2+STrans4+STrans5+STrans7+STrans9+STrans10+STrans11
      +STrans13+STrans16+STrans19+STrans20'
fit <- cfa(model6, data = MasterDataMay_7Final)       `
```

All is good with the above indicators being over .65 loading and the Composite Reliablity is in good shape with the below syntax:
`compRelSEM(fit, obs.var = TRUE, tau.eq = FALSE, ord.scale = TRUE, config = character(0), shared = character(0), higher = 'brandattitude', return.total = FALSE, dropSingle = TRUE, omit.factors = character(0), omit.indicators = character(0), omit.imps = c("no.conv", "no.se"), return.df = TRUE)`
Results:
fluency   transportation        attention        affective        cognitive         conative           Luxury
0.948            0.823            0.901            0.946            0.877            0.902            0.851
transportability    brandattitude
0.940            0.778

But then it got all wrong when trying to get the AVE with the below syntax:
`AVE(fit, obs.var = TRUE, omit.imps = c("no.conv", "no.se"),

- ```
  omit.factors = character(0), dropSingle = TRUE, return.df = TRUE)`
  ```

  fluency   transportation        attention        affective        cognitive         conative           Luxury
  0.820            0.621            0.751            0.789            0.666            0.822            0.570
  transportability
  NA

The second-order latent variable is missing and transportability is NA.  I suspected the syntax is only meant for single level.  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

I expected to have AVE for brand attitude and transportability not being NA

Many thanks for the help in advance